# Проект xCode 6.2 archive failed в xCode 6.3 и Swift 1.2 (swiftc failed with exit code 1)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, swift1.2, xcode6.3

Столкнулся с проблемой после перехода на xCode 6.3 и Swift 1.2:

У меня есть существующий проект, который разрабатывается уже очень давно, начали его еще в xCode 5. Swift используется в нем с момента как он был запущен еще в первой Beta версии. Мне постоянно нужно выпускать обновления для App Store и заказчиков, но теперь я не могу этого делать из странной проблемы, которая появляется **только при архивации проекта. Проект запускается на любом симуляторе или устройстве в режиме Debug.**

Я законвертил код на Swift 1.0 в версию 1.2 вручную, теперь если запустить 
**Edit->Convert->To Latest Swift Syntax**, она говорит, что никаких изменений не требуется и со свифтом все ок.

Вот проблема с самом конце архивации проекта:

`Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1`

[image: xCode archiving error screenshot]

Само собой я пробовал Clean, удаление Derived Data, перезагрузку xCode и прочее. У всей нашей команды после обновления xCode сейчас одна и та же проблема, так что это, очевидно, не относится к моему конкретному компу.

Может кто-нибудь что-то посоветует, что еще можно проверить и попробовать. 
Любая помощь была бы очень кстати, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вот попробуйте в *Build Settings* установить значение в *Swift Compiler*

> **Optimization Level (release): None**

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]